# Ionic camera plugin getPicture ignored

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, cordova-plugins

This is freaking me. I have a simple app where you press a button and it take a picture, then the user can do other stuff but the problem is that sometime the getPicture function is ignored and camera never shows, here goes some info and simple code:

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002

Installed platforms:
  android 6.0.0
  ios 4.3.1
```

plugins installed

```
$ ionic plugin ls
WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
com.googlemaps.ios 2.1.1 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 1.4.0 "phonegap-googlemaps-plugin"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 1.4.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Then we have a HTML with this button

```
<button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="take_picture()">Take photo</button>
```

And the function into the controller

```
$scope.take_picture = function()
{
    screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
    var options = {
        quality: 25,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation: true,
        allowEdit: false,
        targetHeight: 200,
        targetwidth: 200
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI) {
        $scope.image_uri = imageURI;
        $scope.marcar_gps();
        $cordovaCamera.cleanup(); 
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('error ',err);
      $cordovaCamera.cleanup();
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    });

};
```

Hope someone can help.
Best!

---

EDIT

When camera is skipped on xCode console I get this:
Warning: Attempt to present   on  which is already presenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using DATA_URL destinationType and replace it with FILE_URI as it may consume so much memory on the old phones. When you're using FILE_URI as destinationType, you can use cordova file plugin to transfer image to the external/internal storage, then you can call the image src link to your local device url.

---

EDIT

camera plugin and orientation plugin wasn't up to date. So need it to update from versions 2.4.0 "Camera" and 1.4.2 "Screen Orientation" to 2.4.1 "Camera" and 2.0.1 "Screen Orientation"

Comment: but this is happening on an iphone 7, do you think that could be a memory problem in that phone? The timeout is a hack to avoid the user to press too many times the button

Comment: After the photo has been taken, then callback has been called, so that's mean the image is completely returned. You don't need to wrap hideloading in timeout. From http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/ cameracleanup is used if you're using FILE_URI only, not needed if using DATA_URL. Thanks.

Comment: I found that on XCode console, when camera is skipped, it return this Warning: Attempt to present <CDVCameraPicker: 0x1018db000>  on <MainViewController: 0x10100d190> which is already presenting <ForcedViewController: 0x1011976c0>

Comment: Try added return true at the end line in the take_picture function.

Comment: thanks digit, I tried that but still get: Warning: Attempt to present <CDVCameraPicker: 0x114995600>  on <MainViewController: 0x113e0a200> which is already presenting <ForcedViewController: 0x113e78010>

Comment: I think, it is the issue with DATA_URL. The response hasn't finished yet when the button is click. From https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera , "Once the user snaps the photo, the camera application closes and the application is restored".

Comment: digit it works. One more question: as you can see I'm setting width/height to 200 but i'm getting 2448 × 3264 any idea?

Comment: It's bug i think if you're using DATA_URL, FILE_URI is fine for me. Try changing encodingType to Camera.EncodingType.PNG

Comment: but keep in mind that changing the encoding type to PNG will make your camera take pictures with no EXIF information (such as where the picture was taken)

Comment: I'll try that. I'm getting the lat/long from plugin. About main issue: camera plugin and orientation plugin wasn't up to date